# Regex: Match all characters between two strings

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

Example: *In the Netherlands, peanut butter is called "pindakaas" (peanut cheese) rather than "pindaboter" (peanut butter) because the word butter is only supposed to be used with products that contain actual butter.*

I want to match everything between `cheese` and `butter` and viceversa.

Goals:

- butter is called "pindakaas" (peanut cheese
- cheese) rather than "pindaboter" (peanut butter

EDIT:
Language used is Python 3.7 and current reg-exp I'using is `cheese(.*?)butter`.

Comment: What language are you using and what attempts have you made?

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the `regex` package from the `PyPI` repository, then you can do `overlapped` searches:

```
import regex as re

text = 'In the Netherlands, peanut butter is called "pindakaas" (peanut cheese) rather than "pindaboter" (peanut butter) because the word butter is only supposed to be used with products that contain actual butter.'

l = re.findall(r'\bbutter\b.*?\bcheese\b|\bcheese\b.*?\bbutter\b', text, overlapped=True)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['butter is called "pindakaas" (peanut cheese', 'cheese) rather than "pindaboter" (peanut butter']
```

I used your basic regex but required `butter` and `cheese` to be on word boundaries, e.g. `\bbutter\b`, by placing `\b` before and after the words. Feel free to remove or not.

Comment: Neat functionality, I want two hours of my life back. ^^

Comment: I should add that usually people normally: `import regex as re` and use it as an `re` replacement. I will update my answer to reflect normal usage.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your example is, that the last word of your first target is the first word of your second target in the source string; "normal" RegEx syntax makes the RE engine consume the characters it matches, i.e. these characters are not available for further matches.

You can do this - in principle - with Regex flavours like PCRE, using capturing groups in lookahead assertions, since they do not lead to character consumption within the assertion. But, all that asserting has its price in performance. The matches will be in the two capturing groups. Two examples:

Straight approach:

```regex
/
\b(?=(.*?cheese))butter  # match butter, assert that cheese comes after it and capture
|                        # or
\b(?=(.*?butter))cheese  # match cheese, assert that butter comes after it and capture
/gsx                     # flags: global, single line, free spacing
```

Let's take a look at how a successful match of `\b(?=(.*?cheese))butter` works; the same principle is mirrored in the other alternative. The regex engine first looks for a word boundary `\b`, i.e. a position in the text that does not have a word character on both sides. Once found, it will try to assert `(?=(.*?cheese))` at this position. In natural language: "Starting here, find `cheese` as soon as possible. Only if you find it, capture the whole string you just traversed in a numbered group and return the match pointer to where we started. Then, allow matching to continue." If the assertion was successful, matching continues and `butter` is consumed next. We have our match, the match pointer stands behind `butter`, and the regex engine tries the same thing (including the alternative, of course) on the rest of the text.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzOSs2/1).

Somewhat optimized version:

```regex
/
\b(?=((?:[^c]*+|c(?!heese))*cheese))butter
|
\b(?=((?:[^b]*+|b(?!utter))*butter))cheese
/gsx
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzOSs2/2).

Output:

```
Match 1
Full match  27-33   butter
Group 1.    27-70   butter is called "pindakaas" (peanut cheese

Match 2
Full match  64-70   cheese
Group 2.    64-111  cheese) rather than "pindaboter" (peanut butter
```

**OR**

If one is not averse to concatenating matched string and captured string for each match after the fact, this would also work, and would be better performance-wise. (Still likely not as good as the `overlap` solution seen in Booboo's answer.)

```regex
/\bbutter\b.*?\b(?=(cheese))|\bcheese\b.*?\b(?=(butter))/sg
```

This matches each alternative only up until the word boundary before the second term, which allows the next match attempt to begin with that term. The second term is not part of the match string, but is stored in a captured group: `['butter is called "pindakaas" (peanut ', 'cheese'], etc.`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzOSs2/4).

Comment: This is extremely helpful to my regex education. Could you explain how the regex engine (say PCRE) processes the "Straight appoach" regex? Also, if only the part before `|` is present it only matches one substring. Why not later ones as well? A small thing: you need more word breaks to avoid matching "buttermilk" and "headcheese".

Comment: You're right about word boundaries, but I'd leave them out here if just because additional ones don't help with the example as is. Duly noted, though. The first alternative is not matched multiple times, because there is only one occurrence of cheese in the example. I'll try to explain how the assertion part works in an edit. (I _just_ found out you can increase the size of the post edit box... lol.)

Comment: Let me explain what I think is happening (which must be wrong) and then you can correct me. Initially `\b(?=(.*?cheese))` is successful and  cap grp 1 contains text from the beginning of the string up to the first occurrence of "cheese" (which is after the first occurrence of "butter"). The pointer now goes back to the beginning of the string. Next, the first instance of "butter" is matched. How then does the content of cap grp 1 and "butter" generate the string between the first instance of "butter" and the end of the first instance of "cheese" after that instance of "butter"?

Comment: `butter` as a match has nothing to do with what is stored in the capturing group in this situation. If, after making a successful assertion, the engine is not able to match `butter` right after the word boundary, then it will simply drop everything and start from the beginning at the next stop of the match pointer. Only if `butter` is matched, is the capture preserved and goes into the result. Edit: I do not look at failed assertions or matches otherwise in my explanations; of course, the alternative as a whole will fail on all positions of the text except for one.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much! So the engine starts before the first char in the string and fails, because the string does not begin with "butter". Then it moves to the second char of the string and fails again. It keeps going until it is right before the "b" of the first occurrence of "butter". Now the capture group will contain "butter...cheese" and the pointer goes back to right before the "b", "butter" is matched, the match succeeds and the capture group contains what we want. Correct?

Comment: Exactly! And much better explained. :)

Comment: Maybe not a road to Damascus experience, but a road to somewhere experience for sure.